# UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter as Subview

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uiimageview

I'm trying to set the product options if images into UICollectionView with user interaction enabled so user can select the option he/she prefers before adding the product to the cart.

```
@IBOutlet weak var optionView: UIView!
optionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false                 
var Y:CGFloat = -10

        else if dict["type"].stringValue == "image" {
                        let imageOptionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: Y, width: self.optionView.frame.size.width - 10, height: 30))
                        imageOptionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                        self.optionView.addSubview(imageOptionView)
                        imageOptionView.tag = 11000;
                        Y += 60;
                        let productOptionArray : JSON = JSON(dict["product_option_value"].arrayObject!)
                        let imagesArray:NSMutableArray = []
                        var internalY:CGFloat = 0

                        for j in 0..<productOptionArray.count {
                            let img = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: internalY, width: imageOptionView.frame.size.width, height: 30))

                            let images = productOptionArray[j]["image"].stringValue
                            let data = NSData(contentsOf: NSURL(string: images)! as URL)
                            img.image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)

                            img.tag = j;
                            img.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                            imageOptionView.addSubview(img)
                            internalY += 60;
                            imagesArray.add(img)

                            print ("Printing Images", images)
                            print ("Printing ImageView", imageOptionView)
                            print ("Printing One Image", img.image)
                            print ("Printing ImageArray", imagesArray)
                        }
```

Since it's a subview it should follow the main optionview Y position. Once I test the app and try to load the product page the app crashes.

EDIT: Thanks to @Sh_Khan posting an answer now I get a different error:

> The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
>   the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView
>   minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content
>   insets left and right values. The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout
>   instance is , and it is
>   attached to ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0,
>   0}; contentSize: {0, 0}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}>
>   collection view layout: .
>   Make a symbolic breakpoint at
>   UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the
>   debugger.
>   *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3698.54.4/UICollectionView.m:5283
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view
>   of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier catalogimage -
>   must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a
>   prototype cell in a storyboard'

It sounds we're having conflict with another images parsed from JSON

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this initalizer

```
init(frame: CGRect,collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout)
```

//

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 60, height: 30)
let imageOptionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: Y, width: self.optionView.frame.size.width - 10, height: 30),layout:layout)
```

//

You need to register the collectionView with the cell

```
imageOptionView.register(ImagesCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "catalogimage")
```

Or this if you have cell with xib

```
 imageOptionView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "ImagesCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "catalogimage")
```

Here nib name should be **ImagesCollectionViewCell.xib** with class **ImagesCollectionViewCell**

Comment: Sorry might be a silly question where should be init

Comment: Thanks for your support I tried this couple of minutes ago [https://stackoverflow.com/a/40417583/9523050] when I found this answer. But now the returning error is different `The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because: he item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.` I'll edit my post for the full error

Comment: look to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32082726/the-behavior-of-the-uicollectionviewflowlayout-is-not-defined-because-the-cell

Comment: you need to go through this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/975-uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started Or this https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/collection-view-controller-ios-tutorial-ios-11

Comment: Thanks for your share I'll check it now, thanks again!

Comment: I've checked the tutorial I've successfully created a UICollection in a different ViewController and working fine. However this case a bit different since I'm trying to parse product options in a product page that options can be either checkbox, radio, text, date or image. So I'm defining the image to be set in a UICollection rather a UIView so all options will be in one row and allow the customer to pick his option and add item to cart. i hope this clarify my point

Comment: You need to create a UICollectionViewCell subclass and register it , then run and tell if you got any errors preferably create it with xib

Comment: Creating an XIB even if it's a subview and not allows presented?

Comment: xib is a layout for the collection , regardless it's in a subview or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177921/discussion-between-david-buik-and-sh-khan).